# Codeigniter - Add a marker to a Google map using a html form and store in a database

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I am trying to build an application that uses Codeigniter and Google maps. I am new to both and I am trying to allow a user to add a marker to a map using a HTML form and then store it in a database.

I am using Codeigniter and a Google Maps library from [here](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library)

I generate a map using a Maps function in my controller

```
public function maps()
 {

   $data['title']= 'Maps';

   $config['center'] = $_GET['venue_lat'].",". $_GET['venue_long'];
   $config['height'] = '450px';
   $config['width'] = '100%';
   $config['zoom'] = '15';
   $config['trafficOverlay'] = TRUE;
   $config['places'] = TRUE;
   $config['placesLocation'] = $_GET['venue_lat'].",". $_GET['venue_long'];
   $config['placesRadius'] = 3000;
   $config['placesName'] = "church";

   $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

   $marker = array();
   $marker['position'] = $_GET['venue_lat'].",". $_GET['venue_long'];
   $marker['infowindow_content'] = $_GET['venue_name'];
   $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?  chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
   $marker['title'] = $_GET['venue_name'];

   $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

   $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

   $this->load->view('include/reviews_header',$data);
   $this->load->view('pages/reviews_view.php', $data);
   $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
```

}

Controller function to add a service

```
public function services()

 {

  $data['title']= 'Services';
  $this->load->model('addService_model');
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

  $this->addService_model->new_services();

}
```

In my Header I have

```
 <?php 
  echo $map['js']; 
 ?>
```

And my Maps view

```
  <?php
  echo '<div id="map_canvas">';
   echo $map['html']; 
  echo '</div>';
  ?>
```

This all works fine and I am able to dynamically create a map centring it using the coordinates based on the location set by the $_GET variables received from a drop down menu.

I am now trying to allow users to add a marker to the map using a html form and I am unsure of how to go about it.I have a form on in the same view that the map is displayed in.

Form - the action goes to a Services function in my controller

```
 <form id="add_marker" action='<?php echo site_url("user/services") ?>' method="POST">

     <fieldset>

        <legend>Add New Marker to Map</legend>

                <div class="input">
                    <label for="name">Service Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="service_name"id="name">
                </div>

                <div class="input">
                    <label for="address">Service Town</label>
                    <input type="text" name="service_location"id="address">
                </div>

                <div class="input">
                  <label for="address">Service Type</label>
                  <input type="text" name="service_type"id="type">
                </div>

                <div class="input">
                  <label for="address">Service latitude</label>
                  <input type="text" name="service_lat"id="lat" value="document.getElementById('displayLat').value;">
                </div>

                <div class="input">
                  <label for="address">Service longitude</label>
                  <input type="text"name="service_long"id="long">
                </div>

                 <button type="submit" id="submit_btn">Add Marker</button>
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

The Services function calls up my AddService model which sets up the connection to my database for inserting the data from my form

```
<?php  
class AddService_model extends CI_Model {  


  public function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
   }

       function new_services() 

        {

        $service_data = array(
        'service_name' => $this->input->post('service_name'),
        'service_location' => $this->input->post('service_location'),
        'service_lat' => $this->input->post('service_lat'),
        'service_long' => $this->input->post('service_long'),
        'service_type' => $this->input->post('service_type')
         );

        $this->db->insert('service', $service_data);

       } 
/*End of file fixture_model.php*/
/*Location .application/models/fixture_model.php*/ 
?>
```

I am stuck on a couple of points and am confused as to what to do.

I need to allow a user to add a marker using the form but don't know how to get the lat/long coordinates into the form. I can add a marker to the map using the library which also allows me to get the coordinates using an alert but I want to get these into the latitude and longitude inputs on my form.

This code is in my controller and puts a marker on the map

```
$config['onclick'] = 'createMarker_map({ map: map, position:event.latLng });  alert(event.latLng.toString());';
```

I then need to submit the form and insert the values into the Service table in my database.

The second issue I am unsure about is how to achieve this without refreshing the page I am on because I dont want to reset the $_Get variables. If these variables reset I get unknown variable errors.

This is the first time I have used Codeigniter, Google Maps Library or the Google Maps API V3 and I don't know how to approach this across an MVC platform. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wrote [an article](http://heera.it/dynamic-google-map#.U0Man_mSySo) on similar thing long ago, could be helpful to you. It may give some idea but not the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response and your demo. It is an excellent demo - I see that you have a marker on the map when it is initialised. Lots to think about. For my purposes there would be no marker until a user clicked a position on the map which would then drop the marker and show the coodinates of the click point in the text boxes. The user can drag and drop the marker to its final position then click submit to add to the database.